# Error when trying to show Toast from lightning out through Site

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-out

I get this error on the bottom of the page when trying to show a toast message

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Error in $A.getCallback() [$A.getEvt(...) is undefined] Callback failed: apex://StudentRegistrationController/ACTION$saveStudent Failing descriptor: {lightning:notificationsLibrary}

I did as the documentation stands for this:

Aura component:

```
<lightning:notificationsLibrary aura:id="notificationsLibrary"/>
```

Controller:

```
if(state === "SUCCESS") { 
    component.find('notificationsLibrary').showToast({
        "variant": "success",
        "title": "Contact Updated",
        "message": "Contact successfully updated"
    });
    window.setTimeout(
        $A.getCallback(function() {
            window.location.href = "/";
        }), 3000
    );
} else {
    console.error(JSON.stringify(response.getError()));
}
```

Won't work, even if I use:

```
var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
toastEvent.setParams({
    "title": "Success!",
    "message": "The record has been updated successfully."
});
toastEvent.fire();
```

Happens the same.

Web console shows nothing, no error or warning.

What could it be? A bug from Salesforce maybe?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`<lightning:notificationsLibrary>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:notificationsLibrary/documentation) and [`force:showToast`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:showToast/documentation) are both unsupported in the Lightning Out context, because they're handled by the Lightning Experience itself.

Note that the Component Library page for `<lightning:notificationsLibrary>` shows

> Experience
>   Lightning Experience, Lightning Communities, Salesforce Mobile App

while `force:showToast` reads

> This event is handled by the `one.app` container. It’s supported in Lightning Experience, Salesforce app, and Lightning communities.

You won't be able to make use of that built-in functionality without providing some implementation yourself.

Comment: Thank you David, one last question, which approach should I take to implement that? Thanks again

Comment: You'd need to be implementing whatever framework you want to use to display notifications, whether that looks like a Toast message or uses some other display mechanism. Paul's answer below has a link to how SLDS marks up notifications.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is one of the events not supported in Lightning Out, I would suggest adding some markup for the slds notification (https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/notifications/) and have some conditional logic in the controller/helper which sets any messages then displays it.